# Azure Function loading 570 MB .parquet file from blob container to DataFrame

Tags: python, azure-functions, out-of-memory

I'm currently testing Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger for data transformation purposes. I'm using the function for loading .parquet as you can see below, and within 40 seconds after calling the endpoint, it fails with the message 'Invoking Azure function failed with HttpStatusCode - InternalServerError.'.

In logs, I can find this message: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Workers.WorkerProcessExitException : python exited with code 137 (0x89), so I understand that it's because of memory issues.

Do you have any idea how to resolve the problem?

```
def read_parquet_from_blob(storage_account_name, container_name, blob_name):
    try:
        container_client = connect_with_blob()

        logging.info("INITIALIZE BLOB CLIENT")
        # Access the container and blob
        blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob=blob_name)

        logging.info("DOWNLOAD BLOB")

        # Read the blob's content into a Pandas DataFrame
        blob_data = blob_client.download_blob(max_concurrency=10)
        df = pd.read_parquet(io.BytesIO(blob_data.readall()))
        logging.info("BLOB DOWNLOADED")

        return df
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(e)
        message = f"Failed to read Parquet file from blob"
        status = "error"
        return {"status": status, "message": message, "error": str(e)}
```

I've tried to set "max_concurrency" parameter for larger values, but without positive results. However for smaller .parquet files, it's working correctly, but I don't know how to make it work with larger .parquet files.

Answer (score 0):

If you run out of memory and can't change the file size or how you process the data without loading everything in memory your only other option with Azure Functions is to switch from a Consumption plan to a Premium Hosting Plan where you can choose the amount on Memory and CPU that's available to your Function.

Comment: The processing of data is about removing columns, adding some columns based on some maths calculations, joining data frames, etc. so nothing fancy. Do you have any suggestions on how to do that without loading everything in memory (without making it tedious)?

Comment: sorry but I don't really have much expertise in python